# R package development: How does one automatically install Bioconductor packages upon package installation?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have an R package on github which uses multiple Bioconductor dependencies, 'myPackage'

If I include CRAN packages in the DESCRIPTION via `Depends:`, the packages will automatically install upon installation via devtools, i.e.

```
devtools::install_github('repoName/myPackage')
```

This is discussed in Section 1.1.3 Package Dependencies, in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)

Is there a way to streamline this such that packages from Bioconductor are automatically installed as well?

Normally, users install Bioconductor packages via BiocLite, e.g.

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("edgeR")
```

Comment: Note that as of Bioconductor release 3.8 onwards, bioconductor packages are installed with `BiocManager::install()` which can be installed from CRAN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a trick to this where [one needs to add `biocViews:` to the package Description](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/700). That's the only solution I've ever seen to allowing automatic installation of bioconductor dependencies. If you need a couple of examples, then click through the link I posted and scroll down to pull requests referencing that issue, they will generally include the actual example.

Comment: I didn't find the examples in the pull requests you mentioned. However, I did search the github mirror on CRAN. There are DESCRIPTION files with a lone `biocViews:` line before `Depends:`. Others include tags, like `biocViews: Infrastructure, RNA`

Comment: Maybe we should post an example DESCRIPTION so it's *absolutely* clear to future biohackers how this is done...this news needs to spread!

Comment: You don't need anything after `biocViews:`, that alone suffices (see `?devtools::package_deps`).

Answer (score 18):

As suggested, here’s an example showing the relevant lines [from a `DESCRIPTION` file](https://github.com/HannahVMeyer/PhenotypeSimulator/blob/6ba850c74d641278f75e30c4750cb2d545522689/DESCRIPTION#L28) from a [CRAN/GitHub hosted project](https://github.com/HannahVMeyer/PhenotypeSimulator) that has Bioconductor dependencies (truncated):

```
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.0)
biocViews:
Imports:
    methods,
    snpStats,
    dplyr
```

The relevant bit is the empty `biocViews:` declaration, which allows the Bioconductor dependency {snpStats} to be automatically installed.

Comment: r Check() would still fail for me with "Packages required but not available"

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Hard to know what you’re doing wrong without seeing your code. As evidenced by the linked package (which can run `R CMD check` without failure), this works just fine.

Comment: I have a clear repro. I have a DESCRIPTION containing biocViews: and an Import on a bioconductor package. I do a check() it fails, I install the package manually and do a check, it works. The problem is, how is this supposed to work on a CI/CD server? Shouldn't R download the packages itself on a check()?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 No, `R CMD check` doesn’t install packages. The same is true for CRAN packages. If you want to run `check` on CI, the conventional way is to first install the package and its dependencies, and then run `check` on it.

Comment: Thanks, what is the right way to install the package and its dependencies?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 The easiest way is probably via `remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)`. Check out [`r-lib/actions`](https://github.com/r-lib/actions), it’s a comprehensive repository of CI/CD actions for R on GitHub. Even if you’re not using GitHub Actions, these can serve as a template for you.

Comment: I now recommend using `pak::pak()` instead of `remotes::install_deps()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a counter example to other answers. BiocViews is not needed to install Bioconductor dependencies on CRAN. I have a [package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BaseSet) that suggests Bioconductor packages and they are found without using BiocViews.

If you are installing a package from github and it has dependencies on Bioconductor you can use directly `BiocManager::install("user/package")` and it will use `remotes::install_github` internally and pull also packages from Bioconductor (from the right release).

BiocViews is/was used to detect that a package is for Bioconductor by remotes, devtools and sessioninfo among other packages that help the development and testing of packages.
In addition Bioconductor doesn't add a `Repository: Bioconductor` on the provided DESCRIPTION field of the packages, while CRAN adds `Repository: CRAN`.